# What to put at the end of a paper?

Tags: formatting

I have finished a paper describing a 6 months long project. About 8000 words.

I have concluded with a chapter **"Conclusion and Future Perspectives"**.

Now I'm wondering what to put after that. I know I need to put the links to the resources I used and define the technical words and acronyms. But I don't how to format that, and what else to include.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do you already know to which journal you want to submit your paper? Just have a look at their most recent papers and compare how they did it.Then (perhaps first) think about what you want to present and what would suit you best.
- Also, most journals (all good ones) provide a a template where you should be able to clarly see how to format your paragraphs.

Let`s call this part literatur research :)

If you still have absolute no idea how to write it, ask a senior partner/friend/collaborateur or (only in the most critical cases) write or call the publishing company.

I hope this short tips will help you in publishing your work and enjoy research.